# POST JSON with PHP cURL and show JSON response

Tags: php, json, curl

I've looked a lot around on Stack Overflow to find an answer to my issue, but simply can't. I'm trying to post the following JSON

```
<?php

$data_string = '{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "login",
        "id": 1,
        "params": {
          "params": {
            "username": "4321",
            "password":  "1234"
          }
        }
      }';

$ch = curl_init('https://domain.com');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

I don't get any response, even though it works fine with jQuery and AJAX. When I check Chrome's developer tools, the method is GET, which is weird as I set it to POST in the code.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make GET request with your JSON string as request body:

```
$data_string = '{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "login",
        "id": 1,
        "params": {
          "params": {
            "username": "4321",
            "password":  "1234"
          }
        }
      }';

$ch = curl_init('https://domain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,   $data_string );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  'GET');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work with GET, as I need to POST the $data_string and then retrieve the JSON response from the server. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: That depends on the server side. You said that it worked for you when you made a GET request with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to see what your args look like on the receiving end?

To the point of Rookies answer - could it have something to do with how you're passing your postfields?  Generally the postfield param will expect key value arrays or urlencoded strings (key1=val1&).  Without a "key" to your JSON ($data_string) "value" does the server know how to accept the postfields? Could you maybe try the following?

```
// Personal preference here - arrays are easier for me to read
// Create a multi dem array dictionary with your values
$_dictionary = array("jsonrpc"=>"2.0",
                     "method" =>"login",
                     "id"     =>1,
                     "params" =>array("params"=>array("username"=>"4321","password"=>"1234"))
                    );

// json_encode 
$_dictionary = json_encode($_dictionary);

// your $data_string variable will now be in key=value  
$data_string = "mydata={$_dictionary}";

// set $data_string to your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS...
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is 2 years old but its still getting a lot of views.

This looks like a SSL problem. You could try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

for more info read this: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```php
function request($url, $data, $method = "POST", $json = true) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    if ($json) {
        $data_value = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($data_value)));
    } else $data_value = http_build_query($data);

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            if ($json) curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            else curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_value);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, $data_value);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result == false) throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
    curl_close($curl);


    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: must like this "a=1111&b=2222"

```
example 1:
<?php
$useragent = 'PHP Client 1.0 (curl) ' . phpversion();
$post_string="a=1&b=1";
$url_with_get="http://xxx.xxx.com";
$result = @exec("curl -s --connect-timeout 10 --user-agent \"$useragent\" -d\"$post_string\" \"$url_with_get\"");
var_dump($result);
?>

example 2:
<?php
$useragent = 'PHP Client 1.0 (curl) ' . phpversion();
$post_string="a=1&b=1";
$url_with_get="http://xxx.xxx.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_with_get);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
?>

example 3:
<?php
$content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$content = "a=1&b=1";
$server_addr = "http://xxx.xxx.com";
var_dump(http_post($content_type, $content, $server_addr));

function http_post($content_type, $content, $server_addr) {

                $user_agent = 'PHP Client 1.0 (non-curl) ' . phpversion();
                $content_length = strlen($content);
                $context = array(
                        'http' => array(
                                        'method' => 'POST',
                                        'user_agent' => $user_agent,
                                        'header' => 'Content-Type: ' . $content_type . "\r\n" .
                                        'Content-Length: ' . $content_length,
                                        'content' => $content,
                                        'timeout' => 10,
                                )
                );
                $context_id = stream_context_create($context);
                $sock = fopen($server_addr, 'r', false, $context_id);

                $result = '';
                if ($sock) {
                        while (!feof($sock)) {
                                $result .= fgets($sock, 4096);
                        }
                        fclose($sock);
                }
                return $result;
        }
?>
```